# Get the lowest 4 prices for a given ASIN

Tags: python, web-scraping, amazon-marketplace

I found this API on Amazon web services [GetLowestOffersPriceListings](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN.html), I also have my Acess Key, and Secret which i am not able to use.

```
ASIN = ['B07CGKVJ34','B07HJRQXNY']
url = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/ASINList.ASIN.1={}&Action=GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN&MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER\
&Signature={}&AWSAccessKeyId={}'.format(ASIN[0], secret, key)
res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"})
print(res.text)
```

So i think my problem is with url itself, the format is wrong or not correct order.

What i want is to get the lowest 4 prices for a list of ASIN numbers, I am sorry but i can't share key and secret.

Edit 1: this URL opens but now i get API version is missing in the message secction.

Comment: It's hard to say what went wrong without seeing the actual error. What response do you get back?

Comment: '    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '

Comment: try adding `https://` to your url

Comment: @Gad this fixes, but now i get API version is missing

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS)** to query the Amazon Retail Inventory, which is very different to **Amazon Web Services (AWS)** which is used to host your own servers and systems.

You need to prefix the url with `https://`

i.e.

```
https://mws.amazonservices.com/
```

Also, the URL you need to call is actually `https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01`, 
which includes the version. Here is an example from the [Amazon MWS](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_ProcessingBulkOperationRequests.html) documentation:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01
    ?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGUVGFGHNKE2NVUA
    &Action=GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN
    &MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
    &SellerId=A2NK2PX936TF53
    &SignatureVersion=2
    &Timestamp=2012-02-07T01%3A22%3A39Z
    &Version=2011-10-01
    &Signature=MhSREjubAxTGSldGGWROxk4qvi3sawX1inVGF%2FepJOI%3D
    &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
    &MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER
    &ASINList.ASIN.1=B002KT3XRQ
    &ASINList.ASIN.2=B002KT3XQC
    &ASINList.ASIN.3=B002KT3XQM
```

Comment: API version is missing

Comment: Try adding `&Version=2011-10-01` in the query string parameters.

Comment: What error do you have now? Here are the REQUIRED parameters http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/dev_guide/DG_RequiredRequestParameters.html

Comment: <Response [404]>
;Action=GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN&amp;MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&amp;Version=2011-10-01 is not found on this server. API Version is missing</Message>\n  </Error>\n  <Requ
estID>6cf9a80d-5864-4cff-8678-24592c9ae537</RequestID>\n</ErrorResponse>\n'

Comment: Added an example from https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_ProcessingBulkOperationRequests.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190630/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-matt-d).